# ND4J: Generate random number within range

Tags: dl4j, nd4j

If we want to create an `INDArray` of given *rows* and *columns* filled with random number between `0 and 1` we can use:

```
Nd4j.rand(row, cols);
```

But what if we want `INDArray` of given *rows* and *columns* filled with random number between `-5000 and 5000`? 
Moreover, what if each column / *vector* has random number selected from specific range?
For example:

```
row = 2; columns = 3
pool = { {-500, 500}, {100, 100}, {1, 10} }
INDArray = [ [randRange(-500,500), randRange(100,100), randRange(1,10)],
             [randRange(-500,500), randRange(100,100), randRange(1,10)] ]
```

How can this be achieved by harnessing the efficiency of *Nd4j*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use other signatures.

I.e this one:

`Nd4j.rand(long[] shape, double min, double max, org.nd4j.linalg.api.rng.Random rng);`

or this one:

`Nd4j.rand(INDArray target,  double min, double max, org.nd4j.linalg.api.rng.Random rng);`

Comment: perfect! but what if each element of INDArray has to be generated from different random range? (last part of my question)

Comment: There's no "out of box" way to do that, but you can obvious master it yourself, i.e. by applying certain scale to each element individually.